# decided to give 20% hike to those employee whose salary+comm is <1500 Get the list of employee will show his current Salary+comm and revised

Tags: sql

Management has decided to give 20% hike to those employee whose salary+comm is <=1500 and 10% to those whose salary+comm >1500

Get the list of employee which will show his current Salary+comm and revised Salary+comm

```
SELECT first_name FROM employee
UPDATE employee SET salary=salary*20/100
WHERE (salary+comm)<1500
```

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you try?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: I think you need to read the question - it says nothing about an update, it says "Get the list that will be updated, with their existing and new". Look up case statements to get you started.

Comment: @TomC: "decided to give" could be interpreted to need an UPDATE

Comment: Ultimately yes @a_horse_with_no_name, but as a dad of boys who never read the actual question, that's just background info. The question definitely says "Get the list of employees". Anyway - I see the OP likes your answer so he'll find out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but in SQL (as in "standard SQL") it's not possible to combine a SELECT and an UPDATE.

However, with PostgreSQL you could do the following:

```
UPDATE employee 
  SET salary = salary * case 
                          when salary + comm <= 1500 then 1.2
                          else 1.1
                        end
RETURNING employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary, salary + comm;
```

You could also use `returning *` to just show all columns

Answer (score 1):

Your query has some syntax issue. You can not use SELECT and UPDATE together the way you are trying. As you need the list of employee only with their current and incremented salary, SELECT statement is enough for that.

**Note:** Please include the employee_id column in the script if available as it make more sense as more than one employee can have the same first name.

```
SELECT 
first_name,
Salary as Current_Salary,
Comm as Commission,
(Salary + Comm) AS Salary_Plus_Commision,
CASE 
        WHEN (salary+comm) <= 1500 THEN Salary+(salary*20.0/100)
        ELSE Salary+(salary*10.0/100)
END New_Salary
FROM  employee
```

Comment: This is non-standard SQL (`[` is invalid for an identifier in SQL) - you should mention for which DBMS product this works.

Comment: Except the question was to show the revised Salary+Commission. I suspect its `(salary+comm)*1.2` etc. Though not entirely clear. Its just a homework question after all.

Comment: @TomC I think the increment only applicable for the salary part and also the salary amount will be updated only.